# Should I have user stories dealing with the case where user is not authenticated?

Tags: agile, software-development, user-stories, methodology, features

In my software, a lot of services expect user to be authenticated before performing.

In positive scenarios, I have this kind of context:

```
Given I am authenticated
When I create meeting X
Then meeting X is well created
```

I am used to write a symmetrical scenario like this for each of my services that deals with user authentication requirement:

```
Given I am not authenticated  //note the 'not' word
When I create meeting X
Then meeting X is not created
And an authentication error should be thrown
```

It forces developer to handle check of user authentication at the top of the service implementation, to prevent any potential "hacker" or malicious code to call the API (in this example 'meeting creation') directly while not being authenticated.

**Is it a practice I should keep?

Am I right to consider this "defensive" scenario as a real business rule that I may discuss with "Business" team?**

*Note that my acceptance tests do not test through the GUI part, but only directly through the use cases part (services / business rules).*

Comment: Creating tags for [tag:gherkin] or [tag:cucumber] might be useful for questions like these, but might easily slip over the edge into engineering.

Comment: "Given I am not authenticated...When I create meeting X": Something else to think about is why an unauthenticated user can even attempt to create a meeting. This seems like a UX design problem more than a useful test case. As always, YMMV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it is perfectly fine to account for negative cases.

I'm used to seeing this a bit differently. Usually a User Story is one step up 
 like:

> As a user, I'd like to be able to add a meeting on the calendar so that I can track my schedule for the day"

Then I would have both of these as acceptance criteria on that story.

This recommendation is more a matter of style though. I like this because it groups them better so that important business cases don't fall through the cracks. What you are doing is certainly not wrong.

Comment: Seems that your sentence is the label of a feature for me, not of a user story. 
The feature aims to focus on the goal ("I'd like to..."), a user story (scenario) is a path to achieve (or not) it with "Given/When/Then".

Comment: I've definitely had a different experience in terminology, but it sounds like we're on the same page - the "I'd like to" describes the goal and the "Given/When/Then" describes the expected behavior inside of there. Either way, I think it's both good and even important that you are accounting for expected negative behavior. I expect that your testers will uncover more still that need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 4):

### Capture Business Concepts (Not Engineering Steps) In Gherkin

> Is it a practice I should keep?

Maybe. Negative test cases, like boundary conditions, are good things to test from a quality assurance perspective. However, from an engineering or product management perspective, it's worth asking why you need a narrow scenario like this rather than either a more comprehensive feature or a scenario outline. And from a business perspective, low-level details in acceptance tests are generally an anti-pattern.

#### Express the Business Case

For example, rather than having all sorts of odd entry points as separate use cases, a more comprehensive feature might say:

```
Given that a user is not authenticated
When the user performs any action
Then the user is redirected to the login page.
```

This captures the real business case better and more clearly, although you would probably want individual steps or a scenario outline to test all the possible entry points and to be able to report individual failures more effectively.

The benefit of this type of story is that it captures the business logic a lot better than an implementation-centric story does. On the other hand, a failure within one of the steps is a lot less communicative, and requires knowledge of the underlying steps to narrow down specific failures.

There's a middle ground: senario outlines.

#### Use Scenario Outlines

The main problem with expressing only the business domain without also defining some context or targeted use cases is that you can't determine with specificity where a test group is failing. That's where Cucumber scenario outlines can help.

For example:

```
Scenario Outline: force authentication on all pages
  Given an unauthenticated user
  When the user connected to the <function> page
  Then the user should be redirected to the login page.

  Examples:
    | function |
    | meeting  |
    | calendar |
    | profile  |
    | launch thermonuclear warheads |
```

With this type of outline the business goal is clear, and you also have a set of high-level tests that can pass or fail independently of each other. The top-level reporting is both granular and cohesive, while avoiding the sort of "test sprawl" that you would get from adding negative scenarios for each behavior.

### Summary

Testing is more of an art form than a science, so your mileage may vary. However, agile testing should function as self-documenting behavior rather than low-level detail, and acceptance criteria should focus more on business logic or user-visible behavior than on underlying implementation details.

Comment: what is different from my practice in my OP? The fact that I mention the return of an error? sounds too technical even if "abstract" ?  I need it because my acceptance tests target use cases directly, not GUI or any "redirection" mechanism.

Comment: The difference, if I understand it correctly -- at least I would vote for that --, is that you maintain this general requirement in a single place. This simplifies maintenance of requirements (imagine what happens if there is a change regarding this; in your case, you'll have to update many places) and also derivation of test cases or low level technical requirements.

Comment: @Mik378 You're inherently trying to raise *steps* to first class status in your scenarios. While you *can* do this, and the merits of doing so could be argued elsewhere (such as on a site about QA test engineering), this is a site about project management. From a PM perspective, low-level tests and engineering-oriented language shouldn't be first-class project artifacts. In fact, I would consider engineering-level reporting masquerading as "acceptance testing" a serious project smell that should definitely be treated as an anti-pattern. YMMV.

Comment: @CodeGnome I don't think they are low-level tests. A scenario isn't a low-level test but a spec demanded by the Business.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Yes, you may keep it this way.

**Long Answer**

Depending on what you are using the *scenarios* or *business rules* for, there are several ways to write them down

**First case:** The scenario is used for [acceptance criteria](https://www.leadingagile.com/2014/09/acceptance-criteria/)

*Story*

> As a user, I want to create meetings, to...

*Acceptance criteria*

- Authenticated user may create meetings over a GUI / API
- Anonymous users should not be able to create meetings and get an error instead

**First case:** The scenario is used for [acceptance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing) / [regression tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), which are fragmented instructions to click through the application. All these tests should pass after every story (or at least before every release).

**Incomplete example:**

*happy path*

1. open browser -> login screen appears
2. authenticate -> login successful message
3. create a meeting -> see meeting details

*without authentication*

1. open browser -> login screen appears
2. create a meeting -> see creation failed due to authentication error

**Side note**

I would recommend to do the regression tests through the GUI by a user. If they are written well, they can be implemented in code and run automatically.

Comment: What you are calling story, I call it feature. What you are calling criteria, I call it a story or scenario. Those are gherkin terms.

Comment: I see, maybe you replace a tag with gherkin :) Nevermind, besides the terms, is this answer somehow useful?

Comment: Yes, the answer is useful but I disagree about the fact that regressions test should happen through the GUI.
https://8thlight.com/blog/doug-bradbury/2011/04/26/ten-ways-to-do-acceptance-testing-wrong.html (at the end of this article)

Comment: Interesting thoughts :) Just to get this straight, besides regression tests, we are using unit tests, to get fast results (almost no waiting) and automated regression tests every day, checking all acceptance tests on "real" environments (plus several version and DB systems). This way we make sure everythings works as it should, even for small changes. Before that we often had the situation, that too much in our tests was mocked away and gave errors after releasing to other environments.

Comment: I practice ATDD, consisting in acceptance tests being implemented through some TDD cycles (unit tests). As soon as those unit tests pass (incremental algorithm), the concerned acceptance test should pass.

Comment: Uncle Bob (Robert C. Martin) discusses about your way of doing deeply. 
The drawback with your approach is that you couple GUI to business rules. You change the GUI (heavy client to web client for instance), you break the tests about Business rules ...
Furthermore, your tests would be slow, very slow if you take the GUI into account. 
Tests dealing with the GUI should not test business rules, but only GUI things.

Comment: Indeed performance is an issue and yes, changig the GUI forces you to change the test - that's why our business logic is fully tested with unit tests! The regression tests, as we use them, with a GUI, are as near as possible to the users way of doing things, that's why I like them.

Comment: Unit tests are not enough although they look like acceptance tests (https://vimeo.com/68375232). The difference is that acceptance tests is master by the business team, not only developers. Gherkin for instance is about to converse with Business. Gherkin fles are the source of acceptance tests, they should not deal with the GUI.
https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2013/09/26/AT-FAIL.html  ctrl+f => "What changes more than the UI"

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, accounting for negative cases is good.  However, the structure of your negative case is not, because it contains an internal contradiction.

The problem is that you are describing outcomes as if they were user actions.  But they are actually the action the software takes in response to the user action.  Failures have user actions, but the expected output never occurs, because the failure prevents it from actually happening, so a story predicated on the event is never satisfied.

Bad:

> Given I am authenticated
>
> When I create meeting X

Better:

> Given I am authenticated
>
> When I submit a "create meeting" request

This is still operating at the level of the backend, it doesn't refer to specific UI elements such as menus or buttons, and covers network activity not generated by the approved frontend (covering the "hack" concern).

Comment: hmm, I disagree like I explained above. Acceptance tests should not focus on the GUI or controller part but on the use case directly. When you mention "submit"/"request", those are terms of web => gui. Gui is an implementation detail, and details should not be part of acceptance tests. For instance, if your client is a pure console (terminal) rather than web, your acceptance test's terms would be inappropriate.

Comment: I thought about your point. I found the following example that pretty improves the coherence of a scenario: https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/gwt/  (at the bottom).
I like the approach "I attempt to...", meaning that the output is not predictable yet before acting. It is enough abstract to fulfill my UI agnosticism and is similar to your "I submit ...".

Comment: @Mik378: Yes, that should work out well too.